# gcc m68hc11 (hc12) port frame pointer management

Tags: gcc, port

This is the code I get when I compile an empty main function:

```
main:
    movw    _.frame,2,-sp
    sts     _.frame
    ldd     #0
    movw    2,sp+,_.frame
    rts
```

(compiled using the -m68hc12 flag; output is similar without the flag). Other basic functions (not necessarily main and not necessarily empty) follow the same pattern.

I don't understand what _.*frame* is. According to the port's source code, it is supposed to be a **hard** register. There are only 5 hard registers on the hc11 / hc12: D, X, Y, SP and PC. So what does the assembler make of a virtual frame pointer register?

The second part of the problem is the appearance of the frame pointer itself. The port seems to implement the required macros and functions for frame pointer elimination so why isn't it replaced with references to the stack pointer?

**Edit:**

I have found the answer to my question. The m68hc11 port simulates a few hard registers (frame pointer included) by assigning symbolic register names to predefined memory locations. This is done in the larith.asm file, which apparently is more than an arithmetic library.

Answer (score 1):

Not check on the exact gcc source, but I think here the _.frame is just kind of soft register which internal use some global data.

Following link may partly prove this:

http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/gnu-m68hc11/message/3621